# Are Windows questions allowed that use Ubuntu minimally?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have just come across [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674170/windows-10-black-screen-after-moutherboard-logo) where the person wants to fix their Windows 10 installation via some boot repair tools and an Ubuntu LiveUSB, is this really on-topic? I mean I guess it is sort of because they want to use an Ubuntu LiveUSB to do the fixing, however it feels like a bit of a cheaty way just to make it on-topic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree. I guess there are some inherent grey-area questions that are up to interpretation. Due to the subjective nature of such questions, it's best to let AskUbuntu's users self-regulate such questions. If you consider questions off-topic, then label them as such or ignore answering the question. The overall effect will determine whether the users in general agree with your judgement in that case.